# How to make searching for error in logs easier in Java?

Tags: java, logging, splunk

Our team has a huge multi-module Java project which contains a whole bunch of duplicated and non-informative messages in logs, which are sometimes hard to find, even using Splunk. So I am wondering, is there any log wrapper or IDE extension which can give a unique ID for each log message? It will help us to search for the appropriate message/error though all the legacy heap of logs.

Answer (score 0):

There are many suitable logging frameworks in Java that are compatible with Splunk, such as

- [Lof4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/)
- [SL4J](http://www.slf4j.org)
- [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/)
- [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)

However, it will really come down to what you are logging in your actual application.

Some other best practices are listed at https://www.fromdev.com/2016/02/splunk-best-practices.html

If you are looking at monitoring your Java VMs, you can check https://wiki.splunk.com/Community:Monitoring_JVMs